# Facebook Graph API - Error while trying to get user data

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, dialogflow-es, webhooks

I am using the Facebook Dialog flow integration, I need to get user data (First name, Last name, etc.). Through the Dialog Flow webhook, I get the Sender ID, I do authentication, I get a token, and I make a request for this endpoint:
[https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/{person-id](https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/%7Bperson-id) }/

as it is described here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/#Reading

The problem is that in my response this is:
"error": {
"message": "(# 33) This object does not exist or does not support this action",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 33,
"fbtrace_id": "AW9mLNt3WpS7XMfJxHT271U"
}

```
public function webhook( WP_REST_Request $request )
{
    $parameters = $request->get_params();
    $sender_id = $parameters['originalDetectIntentRequest']['payload']['data']['sender']['id'];

    $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token', [
            'body'        => [
                'client_id' => '*********',
                'client_secret' => '*************************',
                'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
            ],
        ]
    );

    $data = json_decode( $response['body'], true );

    $facebook = wp_remote_get( 'https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/'.$sender_id, [
            'body'  => [
                'access_token' => $data['access_token']
            ],
        ]
    );

    return new WP_REST_Response( [], 200 );
}
```

Comment: The token you are creating there is an app access token. You need to use your page access token for this kind of request.

Comment: Could you provide a link where I can see how to get a token for a page?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens